# How can I check with nextLine() if the user input is only a number or also letters?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I´m having a question about my program. I´m trying to figure out, how i can check if the s.nextLine() input form a user is only holding ints form 1 to 49 in it or also letters.
I know that the "eingabe" is a string so I can’t just use an if right?

My problem is, that I´m relative new in programming with java and i have no idea for a solution.  :/
Maybe you can help me that would be great!

```
    public static int Scanner() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String eingabe = s.nextLine();

        //???

        return eingabe;
    }
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!)(`Scanner.nextLine()` returns a `String` with no subsequent relation. You can use any "String function", but have a look at [Java's regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class MyClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
       try {
                int x = Scanner();
                if(x >= 1 && x <= 49) {
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
        }
        catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        //Second Method Using Regex.
        try {
            int x = useRegex();
                if(x >= 1 && x <= 49) {
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
        } catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static int Scanner() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String eingabe = s.nextLine();
        return Integer.parseInt(eingabe);
    }

    public static int useRegex() {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String eingabe = s2.nextLine();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\+-]?\\d+$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(eingabe);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        if(b) {
            return Integer.parseInt(eingabe);
        }

        else {
            throw new java.lang.NumberFormatException();
        }
    }

}
```

Here I am using try catch block to handle if the input format is wrong. If it is wrong then the Exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException

will occur and then if it is a valid number then I am checking whether it is between 1 and 49. [Integer.parseInt(num)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java) is used to convert a String into number. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String).
Try catch is used to handle to exceptions without . [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

By using regex also I have mentioned. [See this for regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

Comment: You should explain what you did rather than just posting code.

Comment: First: Ty thats exactly what i was searching but is it possible that you can explain me what this "try" and "catch" does? I dont know this commands.

Comment: @csm_dev. Now I have edited my answer. Please refer to it.

Comment: Ty very mutch i think i understood the code there :)

Comment: @IceCube. Please accept and upvote answer if it solved your query

Comment: I tryed to upvote but i think its not possible because i just 
registered.